# VBA: refreshing just one pivot table for each external data source

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Okay so I have the following code to refresh all the pivot tables in the active workbook:

```
 For Each oSht In Active Workbook.Worksheets

    For Each oTab In oSht.PivotTables

      oTab.RefreshTable

    Next oTab

Next oSht
```

However, I feel that this is inefficient because, when you refresh a pivot, it automatically refreshes all other pivots connected to the same data table.

I would therefore like to refresh only one pivot table for each external data table i have in the active workbook but cant work out a way of implementing this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches` collection and refresh the cache instead of each table.